# After an alert there is a random segue back to the parent view controller

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu23H.png)I have a view controller that uses a push segue to a tabviewcontroller. On one of the tabs in the view controller there are lots of alerts that show to the user. After the first alert that shows in the tabviewcontroller window at the same time as the alert is showing there is a segue that goes back to the first view controller. There should be no such segue. On my storyboard, there is no segue that shows, so it isn't even possible.

I think it has something to do with the alerts, because after the first alert, a second alert is supposed to appear no matter what they answer. This alert still shows but it shows in the first view controller. Unfortunately, the second alert is asking about if they would like to have an in app purchase. Because I haven't loaded the in app purchases on the view controller the result fails because no in app purchases are found. I don't want to have the in app purchases happen on the other view controller, and the constant segueing after every alert is annoying to the user. I'm not sure how to post my code here but if you have any tips please let me know. I have search for about three hours and I cannot find anyone with a similar problem!

[Two different functions I make alerts from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu23H.png)

I make two different types of alerts that stem from these two functions. The problem that happens during the func createAlert() I think there is something wrong with the way that I dismiss.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your code? It sounds like there is something wrong with how you're calling `dismiss` on the alerts, but it's tough to help without any source code.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the different functions. I hope this helps you understand my problem.

Comment: Do not post images of code. [Edit] your question and copy and paste your actual code as text. Images can't be searched or referenced.